# Minimizing $a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_2^2$ for positive $a_i$, where $a_1x_1+a_2x_2=B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> Find $$\min\{a_1x_1^2 + a_2x_2^2\}$$
> Where $ a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 = B$, and $a_1>0$ and $a_2>0 $. Find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Can we do it usig AG mean inequality?

Let's say we have the problem to find the minimum value of $ x_1^2 + x_2^2 $.

From: $ (x_1 - x_2)^2 ≥0  $,
$ x_1^2 + x_2^2 ≥ 2x_1x_2 $

So the minimum value is:  $2x_1x_2 $ for $x_1=x_2$.

Can be this done in a simillar manner for the starting problem.

why cannot we put $ x^2 =a_1 x_1^2, y^2 =a_2 x_2^2$ and solve it like root mean square inequality (without generalization?) We get:
$x^2 = y^2 $
.
$ a_1 x_1^2 = a_2 x_2^2 $

but not $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with AG. Seems like a Lagrange multiplier problem...

Comment: I mean: $ \sqrt((x_1^2 + x_2^2)/2) >= (x_1+x_2) /2 $

Comment: Would you like to add your any attempts to the question?

Comment: @lonestudent I updated the question. Pls check.

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer Lookup the [weighted power mean inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality), which generalizes the [root mean square inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Root-Mean_Square-Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean-Harmonic_mean_Inequality). You would get $\sqrt{(a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2)/(a_1+a_2)} \ge (a_1x_1+a_2x_2)/(a_1+a_2)$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, why cannot we put $ x^2 =a_1 x_1^2, y^2 =a_2 x_2^2$ and solve it like root mean square inequality (without generalization?) We get:
$x^2 = y^2 $  
.
$ a_1 x_1^2 = a_2 x_2^2 $ 

but not $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer Write down the RMS inequality with your substitution and you'll realize that the right hand side is not what you need i.e. not a constant.

Comment: @dxiv Why does it have to be a constant?

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer Because that (and only that) is how you get the lower bound. Think at how it works for the unweighted case $\min \{ x^2 + y^2 \mid x + y = C \}$. You use $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)/2} \ge (x+y)/2 = C/2$. But if the right hand side is a non-constant function of $x,y$, instead, then it doesn't help you find the minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going along your lines, we can write
\begin{align}
&a_1a_2(x_1-x_2)^2\ge0\\
\iff&a_1a_2(x_1^2+x_2^2)\ge 2a_1a_2x_1x_2\\
\iff&a_1^2x_1^2+a_2^2x_2^2+a_1a_2(x_1^2+x_2^2)\ge a_1^2x_1^2+a_2^2x_2^2+2a_1x_1a_2x_2\\
\iff&(a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2)(a_1+a_2)\ge(a_1x_1+a_2x_2)^2\\
\iff&a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2\ge\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}
\end{align}
This is the required lower bound.

Answer (score 3):

**Use standard algebra:**

We have,

$$\begin{align}a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2&=a_1\left(\frac{B-a_2x_2}{a_1}\right)^2+a_2x_2^2\\
&=\frac{B^2-2Ba_2x_2+a_2^2x_2^2}{a_1}+a_2x_2^2\\
&=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)x_2^2-\left(\frac{2Ba_2}{a_1}\right)x_2+\frac{B^2}{a_1}\end{align}$$

This is the quadratic polynomial. You can minimize the quadratic polynomial with the following method:

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-m)^2+n$$

where, $$m=-\frac{b}{2a}, ~ n=-\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a}$$

---

In this case, we have

$$\begin{align}a:=a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}, ~b:=-\frac{2Ba_2}{a_1} , ~c:=\frac{B^2}{a_1}\end{align}$$

Hence we get,

$$m:=\frac{B}{a_1+a_2},~ n:=\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}$$

Thus,

$$\begin{align}a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_2-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}\end{align}$$

> Finally, we conclude that
> $$\min\left\{a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2 \mid a_1x_1+a_2x_2=B\right\}=\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}$$ which is attained at the point $x_1=x_2=B/(a_1+a_2)$.

Comment: Thanks, but can we do it without using quadraric equation, just the inequality?

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer This is the algebraic method I know.  I don't know any other, unfortunately.

Comment: MathJax looks so bad ...

Comment: The only questionable MathJax I see here is the boxed statement. Particularly because you hide the text `at` in there. At that point it becomes a sentence rather than a displayed formula/equation, and I had to put extra effort into parsing it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much for your comment. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it, how to fix it.  My knowledge is not enough.

Comment: I would consider using features of Markdown to emphasize that sentence, like the alternative I edited in. Not sure, which is best. Also a matter of taste, so I quite understand, if you don't like my suggestion. Furthermore, I cannot test this with the mobile view, for I am too old to understand why anybody would use this site with a screen smaller than 15 inches :-)

Comment: (perhaps "which is attained" is better)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your edit. I am grateful!

Comment: Thanks @Calvin. For the most part my English is adequate, but A) my ear is not attuned well enough to get details like that right, B) lack of practice.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen To keep the solution short, I haven't added the following details: If we substitute $x_1\longmapsto x_2$, or $x_2\longmapsto x_1$,  then we observe $$\begin{align}a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_1-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_2-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}\end{align}$$ Therefore, for minimum we must take $$x_1=x_2=\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Or, for to minimize $a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2$ , after we show that $x_2=\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}$ from the  equation, $$\begin{align}a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_2-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}\end{align}$$ then we find $$x_1=\frac{B-a_2x_2}{a_1}$$ But , I think, it's best to show that $$\begin{align}a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_1-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}=\left(a_2+\frac{a_2^2}{a_1}\right)\left(x_2-\frac{B}{a_1+a_2}\right)^2+\frac{B^2}{a_1+a_2}\end{align}$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you think I should add these details to my answer?  Or is it better to keep the answer like this?  I was undecided..Thank you for any advice!

Comment: It's fine as it is, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I see there's nothing calculus-ish in the tags, so maybe a proof using calculus isn't allowed. If so then it's allowed here:

Lagrange multipliers. $f=a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2$, $g=a_1x_1+a_2x_2$, and we want $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$: $$\begin{align}2a_1x_1=\lambda a_1,
\\2a_2x_2=\lambda a_2,\end{align}$$hence $x_1=x_2$, so $x_1=\dots$ and $x_2=\dots$.

Comment: why cannot we put $ x^2 =a_1 x_1^2, y^2 =a_2 x_2^2$ and solve it like root mean square inequality (without generalization?) We get:
$x^2 = y^2 $  
.
$ a_1 x_1^2 = a_2 x_2^2 $ 

but not $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer I didn't say you couldn't solve it that way. If you don't get this then I'm pretty sure your answer's wrong, because this is so simple... Oh: also this is the same as the other answer above.

Comment: So what is the mistake in these two lines?

$ a_1 x_1^2 = a_2 x_2^2 $ 

but not $x_1 = x_2$?

Comment: @BlueSkiesHighFlyer I'm not going to worry about trying to find the error, sorry.